# Linux distro installation on 64 bit processor

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, 64bit

I am trying to install Ubuntu/Fedora 64 bit versions on my machine and they shout back saying my CPU does not support x86_64 bit architecture and forces me to use i686 versions.

I am currently running Windows 7 64 bit version on my laptop.
 The processor is :  Intel Centrino Core 2 Duo CPU T6500 @ 2.10 GHz

I am hoping this is the right place to ask this question. Why is it that even though I have a 64 bit CPU, I am unable to install Linux 64 bit OS?

Comment: Pretty strange problem. I'd check the BIOS if there are processor capabilities disabled.

Comment: Are you sure you have a 64 bit installation cd? Most linux distros have different images for 64 bit and 32 bit archatectures.

Comment: Please post output of `dmesg | grep CPU` once you boot to shell from the install disc.

Comment: or `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 2):

Either you do not have a 64 bit CPU, or your computer is not properly reporting/presenting itself to the installation disc.

The output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'` should tell you exactly what CPU you have. If it does indeed say its `64 bit` and if there aren't any BIOS weird BIOS options disabled, then I would say you either have a corrupt live CD or you downloaded the wrong version.

Here's the output of my `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'`

```
max@max-desktop:/dev> cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name'
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 6000+
model name      : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 6000+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CPU flags directly to see if it's 64-bit.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "} /^[pl]m$/' < /proc/cpuinfo
lm
lm
```

- `lm` stands for *long mode* and indicates 64-bit.
- `pm` stands for *protected mode* and indicates 32-bit.
- You should see one or the other.

The `lm` flag will be present at least if the processor is 64-bit capable and is enabled in the BIOS, whether you're currently running with 64-bit or 32-bit binaries. You should be able to do this from an i686 Live CD and get the information you need.